# Как в Timer реализовать случайный период повтора?

Tags: java, android, service

Есть такой код метода onStartCommand в Service:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
Handler uiHandler = new Handler();

myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Parsing(); //Здесь выполняется мой метод
      }
    });
  };
), 0L, 1500L * 1000);
```

Как я понимаю сам метод onStartCommand вызывается каждый раз, когда запускается служба методом startService. Вопрос касается последней строки кода:

```
), 0L, 1500L * 1000);
```

В ней задается период повтора выполнения моего метода Parsing(). Сейчас он запускается через каждые 1500 секунд (25 минут). Что изменить здесь, чтобы это время было случайным каждый раз? Например, служба запущена, метод Parsing() выполнился. Следующий его запуск будет через 24 минуты, следующий - 26 минут и так далее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз в минуту проверяем если пора запускаться, запускаемся и рассчитываем время след запуска.

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
Random rnd = new Random();
long nextRun = 0;
int m = 60*1000;
int mean = 25*m;
int from = -5*m;
int to = 5*m;

myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if(System.currentTimeMillis()>nextRun){
      nextRun = System.currentTimeMillis()+mean+from+rnd.nextInt(to-from+1));
      uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          Parsing(); //Здесь выполняется мой метод
        }
      });
    }
  };
), 0L, m);
```

Comment: Ошибка в nextInt(to-from+1)) . Возможно сменить на nextLong, но ошибка остается. NextLong() in Random cannot be applied to (long)

Comment: Сорри, писал в окне ответа. Поправил. В принципе все зависит от вашей задачи. Если вам надо варьировать с точностью до минуты, то множитель минут можно вынести за nextInt. Если вы уверены, что не вылетите за границы int, можно оставить как в ответе. Если заранее интервалы неизвестны, то можно воспользоваться nextDouble(), который вернет число из [0,1), его уже умножить и привести к long...

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Это то,  что мне было нужно. Но сейчас еще одна ошибка с nextRun: просит обозначить ее как final. Как быть?

Comment: Вынести ее в поле класса. Если метод статический - вынести в статическое поле класса. Есть еще костыльный метод: создать `final long[] nextRun = {0L};` и обращаться к нулевому элементу этого массива. Кстати rnd вам тоже создавать лучше не при вызове метода, а один раз. Ну или пользоваться `new Random(seed)`, где `seed` может быть константой или текущим временем...

Answer (score 0):

Эм

```
public static long nextLong(long n) {
    if (n < 0)
        return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(-n) * -1;
    else if (n == 0)
        return 0;

    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(n);
}

public static int get(long min_, long max_) {
    final long min = Math.min(min_, max_);
    final long max = Math.max(min_, max_);

    return min + nextLong(max - min + 1);
}
```

используете get(...) где выставляете границы перебора

к примеру

```
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Parsing();
      }
    });
  };
), 0L, get(1000000, 1600000));
```

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то этот код делает именно то что вы хотите. Таймер срабатывает с фиксированным интервалом, но внутри метода `run` производится проверка. Если время предыдущего запуска меньше, чем произвольное значение, то поток ждет.

```
public static void startTimer(){

    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        private long prevTime = 0;
        private long nextPeriod = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            nextPeriod = getRandomSecondCount();

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && System.currentTimeMillis() - prevTime <= nextPeriod) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(System.currentTimeMillis() - prevTime);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            System.out.println("работать: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - prevTime));
            prevTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}

private static long getRandomSecondCount() {
    long period = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt(10_000);
    System.out.println("period: " + period);
    return period;
}
```

Comment: Слипание потоков? Вы хотите в конец убить приложение в UFE?

Comment: @GenCloud я не совсем понимаю, с каких пор усыплять потоки стало плохо? и что такое UFE (не могу нагуглить)?

Comment: отправлять в спячку трид, чтобы делать что-то с нужной задержкой - это нехорошо. Если это высоконагруженное приложение  - проц скажет гудбай через определенное время

Comment: Хорошо, в таймере сидит поток который бегает по очереди и вытаскивает таски, при этом вызывая метод `wait`. Разве это сильно оптимальнее чем вызов метода `sleep`? И там и там поток паркуется и происходит переключение контекста в процессоре.

Comment: lulz, а Вы простите вообще читали что ТСу требуется? :/ Шедуль потока с срабатыванием в различное время. А то что Вы дичь написали это и так понятно. А точ то тс пишет такой это сугубо его проблемы, рандомайзер времени на ответ дан

Comment: Это вы товарищ,  дичь пишете, не разбираясь в теме делаете ложные умозаключения.

Comment: ясно... вопросов более не имею

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov если правильно понял, вы раз в секунду запускаете задачу, которая будет выполнена через определенное время. итого через 25 минут таких задач наберется около 1500 штук и все они станут выполняться...

Comment: @YuraIvanov не совсем. Timer - однопоточен. У него есть очередь запланированных задач. Но в этой очереди в моем примере только одна задача. Эту задача запускается каждую секунду, но мы усыпляем  поток который ее запустил на рандомное время. Соотвественно, здесь не копится никаких задач, очередь не раздувается.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov понял. Только не понял зачем нужен таймер, если вы используете его внутренний поток как свой. Для перезапуска задач можно с таким же успехом просто цикл сделать... И по поводу очереди есть сомнения, память использованная растет (глубоко не копал, но есть подозрения не хорошие).

Comment: @YuraIvanov согласен, можно было обойтись и обычным тредом. По поводу памяти, как вы определили?  в моей профайлере я не увидел роста потребляемой памяти.

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov не, по памяти все ок. Уж больно неочевидный алгоритм...